# Ubuntu 18.04 Yarn Binaries of Globally Installed Packages

Tags: ubuntu, yarnpkg, ubuntu-18.04

I installed Yarn on my Ubuntu machine and installed the now-cli using Yarn. However `now` wasn't a command that was recognised by the terminal. After doing some searching, I found that the solution was to include this line in the `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/edward/.yarn/bin"
```

So after sourcing my `.bashrc` file, it works as expected. However when I restart my machine, the command once more, isn't recognised. I have to manually make a change in my `.bashrc` file and then source it again for it to work.

I'm wondering how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Perhaps export PATH="/home/edward/.yarn/bin:$PATH" ... Then after that you need to source your .bashrc and in order to do this you do the following: source ~/.bashrc

Comment: @JoeA hi I just tried it and restarted. Again the command isn't recognised.

Comment: Hi it should work after updating the bashrc check this thread out to verify you did it correctly https://askubuntu.com/questions/312163/path-variable-gets-always-reset-how-to-fix-that

Comment: Yes you're right. I had made a typo. Thank you for helping me with this issue.

Comment: That's good perhaps posted how you solved the issue. For others to see

Comment: Good idea. I just posted the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having `export PATH="$PATH:/home/edward/.yarn/bin"`, I added the line `export PATH="/home/edward/.yarn/bin:$PATH"` in `.bashrc`, sourced the file and it worked correctly. Thanks to Joe A in the comments for helping me with this issue.